# Using state in other components in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I have three components.

```
export default class PermissionHandler extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            permission: true
        }
    }

}

export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <PermissionHandler />
            <Component1 />
        )     
    }
}

export default class Component1 extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <SomeComponent /* visible= true/false depends on permission */ />
        )     
    }
}
```

I want PermissionHandler state to be used by any other components directly without using events or local state. Is it possible?

Can I use refs to achieve this goal?

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.permissionHandler = React.createRef();
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <PermissionHandler ref={this.permissionHandler} />
            <Component1 permissionHandler={this.permissionHandler}/>
            <Component2 permissionHandler={this.permissionHandler} />
        )     
    }
}

export default class Component1 extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <SomeComponent visible={this.props.permissionHandler.currenct.state.permission} />
        )     
    }
}
```

But Component1 doesnt rerender when the state of PermissionHandler updates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply [move your state up the tree](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html), to the App component